# What are those yellow stripes on the Pokemon Go map?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've seen several yellow stripes on the Pokemon Go map around my city. They look as if they are a road or a trail of some kind they are always straight. They never correspond to anything on the ground, nor anything on Google maps.

In this example the stripe goes literally into nowhere.

[image: desert trail]

Comment: This looks like an error in the map parser or an outdated source map. Maybe there was something at the time the map was created.

Comment: @dly, There was never something there, the road in the picture is the "border" of the city, beyond it there is just desert, and there was never something there

Comment: Then it's the other option.. a bug (or feature) with the map parser or files.

Comment: might be some old/new road indicator

Answer (score 3):

After having looked through a few [threads](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4uzsq7/what_is_this_long_yellow_line/), it seems to be happening in many places. And as such it's probably due to an error with the map itself.

[image]
[image]

In this situation, the road seems to "collide" with itself.

Comment: I actually have a road that sort of collides with itself, and there is a yellow stripe and a gray stripe that veer off from the same point in opposite directions. I'll try get a picture next time I see it.